# primeng styles don't appear

Tags: angular, primeng, angular12

I'm using primeng, but the styles kinda don't appear. I added a simple grid into a component and the result is presented on the image below. I deleted `node_modules` and `npm install`'d again, but nothing changes.

I don't know what else I could be missing. Basically, I did everything from [getting started](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup) page.

[image]

#### schedule.component.html

```
<div class="p-grid">
  <div class="p-col-4">4</div>
  <div class="p-col">1 </div>
  <div class="p-col">1 </div>
  <div class="p-col">1 </div>
  <div class="p-col">1 </div>
  <div class="p-col">1 </div>
  <div class="p-col">1 </div>
  <div class="p-col">1 </div>
  <div class="p-col">1 </div>
</div>
```

#### angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "academic-schedule": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/academic-schedule",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/fluent-light/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "academic-schedule:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "academic-schedule:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "academic-schedule:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "academic-schedule",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "academic-schedule",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "format:check": "prettier \"src/{app,environments}/**/*{.ts,.html,.json,.scss}\" --check",
    "format:write": "prettier \"src/{app,environments}/**/*{.ts,.html,.json,.scss}\" --write"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^12.1.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.7.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.8.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

#### schedule.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-schedule',
  templateUrl: './add-schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-schedule.component.scss']
})
export class AddScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
  events!: any[];

  options: any;
  theCheckbox: boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let draggableEl = document.getElementById('external-events')!;
    var self = this;

    new Draggable(draggableEl, {
      itemSelector: '.fc-event',
      eventData: function (eventEl: any) {
        console.log(eventEl);
        if (self.theCheckbox) {
          eventEl.parentNode.removeChild(eventEl);
        }
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText
        };
      }
    });

    this.events = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2017-02-01'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2017-02-07',
        end: '2017-02-10'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2017-02-09T16:00:00'
      }
    ];

    this.options = {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
      defaultDate: '2017-02-01',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      editable: true
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.cloudhadoop.com/primeng-styles-notworking/ hope this will help you

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, I tried adding the styles to `styles.scss` as imports, but still the same, which means it's not the styles. It's something else.

Comment: any other console error you have seen ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, https://i.imgur.com/BAi8WZv.png yes

Comment: is fullCalender dependency working right ? and do you use SSR ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, I just matched every single file to angular 12's default project and now it's 1:1. However, the error is now https://i.imgur.com/RA1xewI.png. Added the TS file to the question.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, nvm that's not the problem. When I commented the code, there were no errors and the styles were still not appearing.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, yes, FullCalendar dependencies are there. What does SSR mean?

Comment: try to replace your code before this line `this.events` in ngOnInit() to `ngAfterViewInit()` . from `schedule.component.ts` file

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, I commented out the FullCalendar code. The problem is that the system doesn't work.

Comment: well in this case you need to uninstall angular locally and globally and try to reinstall it. Its very hard to predict whats going on wrong at this stage.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, I basically did that. The styles are now working https://i.imgur.com/cQS48A4.png, but the grid system is still not working. Maybe there is some additional CSS for the grid?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-primeflex-gridsystem-demo?file=angular.json

Comment: https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/primeflex

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, it says https://i.imgur.com/1H853UN.png for a few styles. What does that mean?

Comment: it means css files is not loaded properly. "./node_modules/primeflex/src/_grid.scss", try to add this inside angular.json file style array

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, https://i.imgur.com/TngTLtS.png `"./node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",` it's in angular.json

Comment: You can try to add all .scss as shown in above comment primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/primeflex

Comment: Problem solved, I accidentally typed the styles under karma's testing styles. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Glad!! You solve it. Consider me in case in future requiremet.